# Working web proxy to acces blocked content

Tags: gratis, proxy

Some of you might know this problem, want to watch a video on youtube, but got the mesage, that video is not avaible in your country. On some other websites you even geting mesage about content not avaible in the region. In the past I used web proxies to solve this problem, but now they all are not working anymore. Results found by Google are also not working. Since Google search is limited to your country as well, this could be the reason why it´s results are useles.
Is there some working web proxy to acces blocked content? I am not interested in any VPN or other comercial stuf, as I am not willing to pay any money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when it comes to videos, I would recommend [proxyium](https://www.proxyium.com/). It helped me, but when it comes to youtube's own restrictions, I'm not sure if they can be bypassed.

If using Firefox private browsing mode must be deactivated.

Comment: Unfortunatelly not working, it says "Your web browser is not supported", but I have the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: "If you are already using Mozilla Firefox browser please make sure you are not in private browsing mode" Did you read that? Just have to disable this private browsing mode.

Comment: Great, it worked and now I can finaly watch bloked TV. But Information about Firefox should be added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution to my question seems to be [KPROXY](https://www.kproxy.com/). Unfortunatelly it seems to be useles for youtube and other video conten sites, but at least some blocked sites can be viewed.